# Working in teams using github

Tags: github, git-workflow

Which is the preferred way when working in teams on a github project? Should each member have it's own fork or should I create an organisation where the main project is and everyone in the team makes a clone of the project?

Comment: I recommend watching the video presentation "How GitHub Uses GitHub to Build GitHub" by Zach Holman http://goo.gl/AUOvd which explains the Git workflow that Github employees are using to build Github. For me the video fails to load on Firefox, if that is the case for you also, try: http://goo.gl/8Hc9D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **[Organization](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations)** is the easiest way for your team to collaborate directly to *one* GitHub repo.
See "[User, Organization and Project Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages)".
That allows you to manage a *group*-owned repository (or repositories).

You can even [convert an existing account (user) into an organization](https://help.github.com/articles/converting-a-user-into-an-organization).

Note that in all cases (fork or organization), a *local* clone will be needed for any team member to work on a project.
The question is: what that local clone is cloning? Your initial repo, or one of the multiple forks created by your team members?
Managing one centralized repo is easier.

Answer (score 0):

To me, forking suggests a permanent divergence, whereas that's definitely not the case for a team project. So go with the usual clone and merge workflow.